# How to apply a concurrent solution to a Producer-Consumer like situation

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, c++11, producer-consumer

I have a XML file with a sequence of nodes. Each node represents an element that I need to parse and add in a sorted list (the order must be the same of the nodes found in the file).

At the moment I am using a sequential solution:

```
struct Graphic
{
    bool parse()
    {
        // parsing...
        return parse_outcome;
    }
};

vector<unique_ptr<Graphic>> graphics;

void producer()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N_GRAPHICS; i++)
    {
        auto g = new Graphic();

        if (g->parse())
            graphics.emplace_back(g);
        else
            delete g;
    }
}
```

So, only if the graphic (that actually is an instance of a class derived from `Graphic`, a Line, a Rectangle and so on, that is why the `new`) can be properly parse, it will be added to my data structure.

Since I only care about the order in which thes graphics are added to my list, I though to call the parse method asynchronously, such that the *producer* has the task of read each node from the file and add this graphic to the data structure, while the *consumer* has the task of parse each graphic whenever a new graphic is ready to be parsed.

Now I have several consumer threads (created in the main) and my code looks like the following:

```
queue<pair<Graphic*, size_t>> q;
mutex m;
atomic<size_t> n_elements;

void producer()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N_GRAPHICS; i++)
    {
        auto g = new Graphic();
        graphics.emplace_back(g);
        q.emplace(make_pair(g, i));
    }

    n_elements = graphics.size();
}

void consumer()
{
    pair<Graphic*, size_t> item;

    while (true)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);

            if (n_elements == 0)
                return;

            n_elements--;
            item = q.front();
            q.pop();
        }

        if (!item.first->parse())
        {
            // here I should remove the item from the vector
            assert(graphics[item.second].get() == item.first);
            delete item.first;
            graphics[item.second] = nullptr;
        }
    }
}
```

I run the producer first of all in my main, so that when the first consumer starts the queue is already completely full.

```
int main()
{
    producer();

    vector<thread> threads;

    for (auto i = 0; i < N_THREADS; i++)
        threads.emplace_back(consumer);

    for (auto& t : threads)
        t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The concurrent version seems to be at least twice as faster as the original one.
The full code has been uploaded [here](https://ideone.com/p341du).

Now I am wondering:

- Are there any (synchronization) errors in my code?
- Is there a way to achieve the same result faster (or better)?

Also, I noticed that on my computer I get the best result (in terms of elapsed time) if I set the number of thread equals to 8. More (or less) threads give me worst results. Why?

Comment: I'd say you should ask this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Processor of your pc has is quad core ? There are procesors with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading technology where one core can execute two threads in parallel. So 4 * 2 = 8 -> each thread has its own 'virtual' core .... No thread switching

Comment: @RobertWadowski Hyper-threading doesn't prevent context switching. You are confusing things in a big way. Context switching will occur on a one CPU - one core machine in a preemptive environment (post DOS :))

Comment: I read about it a long time about but systems tends to assigns threads to same core as far I remember. Context switching occurs indeed ...

Comment: Context switching is prevented when the number of threads <= number of (virtual) cores.  So 8 threads on a quad core with hyperthreading means eight threads on eight virtual cores.  If you had more threads, they would need to 'share' cores, ie context switch.

Comment: use queue.size() instead of n_elements.  Why maintain information that is already maintained and easily accessible?

Comment: You could also try measuring an implementation that uses an atomic counter per thread where the counter value is used as an index for which item to process ( this would require changing your structure from a `queue` to a `vector`). This avoids the potential deallocation and longer wait time that your consumer threads may currently be experiencing in the critical section.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
>   There isn't synchronization errors, but I think that the memory managing could be better, since your code leaked if `parse()` throws an exception.

There isn't synchronization errors, but I think that your memory managing could be better, since you will have leaks if `parse()` throw an exception.

> Blockquote
>   Is there a way to achieve the same result faster (or better)?

Probably. You could use a simple implementation of a thread pool and a lambda that do the parse() for you.

The code below illustrate this approach. I use the threadpool implementation 
[here](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>
#include <ThreadPool.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;



#define N_GRAPHICS        (1000*1000*1)
#define N_THREADS       8


struct Graphic;
using GPtr = std::unique_ptr<Graphic>;

static vector<GPtr> graphics;

struct Graphic
{
    Graphic()
        : status(false)
    {
    }


    bool parse()
    {
        // waste time
        try
        {
            throw runtime_error("");
        } 
        catch (runtime_error)
        {
        }

        status = true;
        //return false;
        return true;
    }


    bool status;
};


int main()
{
    auto start = system_clock::now();

    auto producer_unit = []()-> GPtr {
        std::unique_ptr<Graphic> g(new Graphic);
        if(!g->parse()){
            g.reset(); // if g don't parse, return nullptr
        }
        return g;        
    };

    using ResultPool = std::vector<std::future<GPtr>>;
    ResultPool results;
    // ThreadPool pool(thread::hardware_concurrency());
    ThreadPool pool(N_THREADS);
    for(int i = 0; i <N_GRAPHICS; ++i){
     // Running async task
     results.emplace_back(pool.enqueue(producer_unit));
    }

   for(auto &t : results){
        auto value = t.get();
        if(value){
          graphics.emplace_back(std::move(value));
        }
    }

    auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now() - start);
    cout << "Elapsed: " << duration.count() << endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < graphics.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!graphics[i]->status)
        {
            cerr << "Assertion failed! (" << i << ")" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

It is a bit faster (1s) on my machine, more readable, and removes the necessity of shared datas (synchronization is evil, avoid it or hide it in a reliable and efficient way).